# Why can't I access data() using 'this' directly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I work on Vue2 app. What I have noticed is sometimes I can't access elements stored in `data()` using `this` directly in my code. What I mean by that is that sometimes I need to assign `this...` to a variable inside a method to make it work instead of simply refer to data element by `this`.

I created reproducible example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-vuex-drag-and-snap-to-tiles-this-usage-trhd72?file=/src/components/ZimModel.vue

Please take a look at method `addRegals()`. I used `this.size` everywhere in this method but what I got in console is this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "regalsTotalNumber":
> "TypeError: this is undefined"

I don't get why there's an error if I simply refer to `data()` element using `this`.
To make my code work you need to uncomment code in this method (and comment not working lines). It all starts with assigning `data` element to variable:

```
var size = this.size;
```

I don't understand why I need to make a variable and assign `this.size` to it instead of explicitly using `this` in my method. Same situation with `var tiles = this.thetiles` in the same method (I also need to assign it to var to make it work in this method).

Method `addRegals` is triggered in `watcher`. Maybe here is a problem?

PS. Please type '120' as length, '55' as width in input fields (give it a few sec to show the grid on a screen), then type some number in 'Regals number' field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a local function named `getPos` inside the `addRegals` method. The only problem is that `getPos` does not share `this` with `addRegals`. However, when you declare the variable, it is available in the `getPos` closure.

The solution would either be to make `getPos` a local [lambda function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or make it a method.

You can read more on this in Javascript here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complete-guide-to-this-in-javascript/.

Comment: I wrote this: `const getPos = (col, row) => {return new Point(tiles.x + col*(this.size), tiles.y + row*(this.size)); };` and used here: `var p = getPos(pawn.col, pawn.row);` but got an error: `TypeError: getPos is not a function`

Comment: Ok, I put this lambda function above  `var p = getPos(pawn.col, pawn.row);` and it works. Thanks for clarification!